# do i have to 'build' a site when it's remote to add new webmethods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I'm deploying a site for the first time and after the initial upload of my files and a succesfull run through the site, I noticed that no further changes I was making to the CS files was making a difference on refreshes of the pages. I know i have to build my solution locally before seeing changes to CS, but i have no remote installation of visual studio on this server or anything, i'm just uploading files through FTP

what do I need to do? resetting IIS and editing the web config didn't help

Comment: They should recompile automatically.  Check the date/time stamp on the files and the date time of the server. It's also possible the pages are cached somewhere.

Comment: i've tried private browsing and that didn't solve anything. i'm clearly not seeing what would be considered a new build

Comment: Private browsing (aka "porn mode") will not stop pages from being cached at the server or intermediate proxy servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the project type. Is it a web site or web application? Web sites dynamically compile (e.g. asp.net watches files and if .cs or .config files change, it will reload the site), web apps precompile into DLLs. It sounds like you have a web application though, so you'll have to deploy the DLLs instead of the cs files. In fact you do not need any cs files on your server in this case.

Just recompile locally, look in the bin directory of your web app, sort by last modified and you'll see the DLLs that get updated - these should get moved to the corresponding bin folder of your server